# Generic stack implementation (revision)

Tags: c, generics, stack, library

The below post is a follow-up of [Generic stack implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/290809/generic-stack-implementation).

Below follows a header-only implementation of a generic stack (inspired by [stb-libraries](https://github.com/nothings/stb), following these guidelines: [stb-howto.txt](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/docs/stb_howto.txt)). After incorporating @Coderodde's advice into the code, I am left with:

```c
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

/* To use, do this:
 *  #define STACK_IMPLEMENTATION
 * before you include this file in *one* C file to create the implementation.
 *
 * i.e. it should look like:
 * #include ...
 * #include ...
 *
 * #define STACK_IMPLEMENTATION
 * #include "stack.h"
 * ...
 *
 * To make all the functions have internal linkage, i.e. be private to the
 * source file, do this:
 * #define IO_STATIC
 * before including "stack.h"
 *
 * i.e. it should look like:
 * #define STACK_IMPLEMENTATION
 * #define STACK_STATIC
 * #include "stack.h"
 * ...
 *
 * You can define STACK_MALLOC, STACK_REALLOC, and STACK_FREE to avoid using 
 * malloc(), realloc(), and free().
 */

#ifndef STACK_DEF
    #ifdef STACK_STATIC
        #define STACK_DEF   static
    #else
        #define STACK_DEF   extern
    #endif                          /* STACK_STATIC */
#endif                              /* STACK_DEF */

#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER) 
    #define ATTRIB_NONNULL(...)             __attribute__((nonnull(__VA_ARGS__)))
    #define ATTRIB_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT       __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
    #define ATTRIB_MALLOC                   __attribute__((malloc))
#else
    #define ATTRIB_NONNULL(...)             /**/
    #define ATTRIB_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT       /**/
    #define ATTRIB_MALLOC                   /**/
#endif                          /* defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER) */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct stack Stack;

/*
 * Creates a stack with `cap` elements of size `memb_size`. 
 *
 * The stack can only store one type of elements. It does not support
 * heterogeneuous types. 
 *
 * Returns a pointer to the stack on success, or NULL on failure to allocate 
 * memory.
 */
STACK_DEF Stack *stack_create(size_t cap, size_t memb_size) 
    ATTRIB_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT ATTRIB_MALLOC;

/* 
 * Pushes an element to the top of the stack referenced by `s`. It automatically
 * resizes the stack if it is full.
 *
 * Whilst pushing an element, there's no need of a cast, as there is an implicit
 * conversion to and from a void *.
 *
 * On a memory allocation failure, it returns false. Else it returns true.
 */
STACK_DEF bool stack_push(Stack *s, const void *data)
    ATTRIB_NONNULL(1, 2) ATTRIB_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT;

/*
 * Removes the topmost element of the stack referenced by `s` and returns it. 
 * If the stack is empty, it returns NULL.
 *
 * The returned element should be casted to a pointer of the type that was 
 * pushed on the stack, and then dereferenced.
 * 
 * Note that casting to a pointer of the wrong type is Undefined Behavior, and
 * so is dereferencing to performing arithmetic on a void *.
 */
STACK_DEF void *stack_pop(Stack *s) ATTRIB_NONNULL(1);

/* 
 * Returns a pointer to the topmost element of the stack referenced by `s`
 * without removing it.  If the stack is empty, it returns NULL.
 */
STACK_DEF const void *stack_peek(const Stack *s) ATTRIB_NONNULL(1);

/*
 * Returns true if the capacity of the stack referenced by `s` is full, or false
 * elsewise.
 */
STACK_DEF bool stack_is_full(const Stack *s) ATTRIB_NONNULL(1);

/*
 * Returns true if the count of elements in the stack referenced by `s` is zero,
 * or false elsewise.
 */
STACK_DEF bool stack_is_empty(const Stack *s) ATTRIB_NONNULL(1);

/* 
 * Returns the count of elements in the stack referenced by `s`.
 */
STACK_DEF size_t stack_size(const Stack *s) ATTRIB_NONNULL(1);

/*
 * Destroys and frees all memory associated with the stack referenced by `s`.
 */
STACK_DEF void stack_destroy(Stack *s) ATTRIB_NONNULL(1);

#endif                          /* STACK_H */

#ifdef STACK_IMPLEMENTATION

#if defined(IO_MALLOC) != defined(IO_REALLOC) || defined(IO_REALLOC) != defined(IO_FREE)
    #error  "Must define all or none of IO_MALLOC, IO_REALLOC, and IO_FREE."
#endif

#ifndef STACK_MALLOC
    #define STACK_MALLOC(sz)       malloc(sz)
    #define STACK_REALLOC(p, sz)   realloc(p, sz)
    #define STACK_FREE(p)          free(p)
#endif

struct stack {
    void *data;
    size_t size;
    size_t cap;
    size_t memb_size;
};

STACK_DEF bool stack_is_full(const Stack *s)
{
    return s->size == s->cap;
}

STACK_DEF bool stack_is_empty(const Stack *s)
{
    return s->size == 0;
}

STACK_DEF const void *stack_peek(const Stack *s)
{
    if (stack_is_empty(s)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return (char *) s->data + (s->size - 1) * s->memb_size;
}

STACK_DEF Stack *stack_create(size_t cap, size_t memb_size)
{
    if (cap == 0 || memb_size == 0 || cap > SIZE_MAX / memb_size) {
        return NULL;
    }

    Stack *const s = STACK_MALLOC(sizeof *s);

    if (s) {
        /* Would it be an improvement to round this up to the nearest
         * multiple/power of 2.
         */
        size_t total_size = memb_size * cap;
        s->data = STACK_MALLOC(total_size);

        if (s->data) {
            s->cap = cap;
            s->size = 0;
            s->memb_size = memb_size;
        } else {
            free(s);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return s;
}

STACK_DEF bool stack_push(Stack *s, const void *data)
{
    if (s->size >= s->cap) {
        /* If we cannot allocate geometrically, we shall allocate linearly. */ 
        if (s->cap > SIZE_MAX / 2) {
            if (s->cap + BUFSIZ < s->cap) {
                return false;
            }
            s->cap += BUFSIZ;
        } else {
            s->cap *= 2;
        }

        if (s->cap > SIZE_MAX / s->memb_size) {
            return false;
        }

        void *const tmp = STACK_REALLOC(s->data, s->cap * s->memb_size);

        if (!tmp) {
            return false;
        }

        s->data = tmp;
    } 

    char *const target = (char *) s->data + (s->size * s->memb_size);

    memcpy(target, data, s->memb_size);
    return !!++s->size;
}

STACK_DEF void *stack_pop(Stack *s)
{
    if (stack_is_empty(s)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    --s->size;
    void *const top = (char *) s->data + (s->size * s->memb_size);
        
    if (s->size && (s->size <= s->cap / 4)) {
        void *const tmp = realloc(s->data, s->cap / 2 * s->memb_size);
        
        if (tmp) {
            s->data = tmp;
            s->cap /= 2;
        } 
        /* Else do nothing. The original memory is left intact. */
    }
    
    return top;
}

STACK_DEF void stack_destroy(Stack *s)
{
    STACK_FREE(s->data);
    STACK_FREE(s);
}

STACK_DEF size_t stack_size(const Stack *s)
{
    return s->size;
}

#endif                          /* STACK_IMPLEMENTATION */

#ifdef TEST_MAIN

#include <assert.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* We could support heterogenuous objects by using void pointers. */
    Stack *stack = stack_create(SIZE_MAX - 1000, sizeof (size_t));
    assert(!stack);

    stack = stack_create(1000, sizeof (int));
    assert(stack);

    for (int i = 0; i < 150; ++i) {
        assert(stack_push(stack, &i));
    }
    
    assert(!stack_is_empty(stack));
    assert(stack_size(stack) == 150);
    assert(*(int *) stack_peek(stack) == 149);

    for (int i = 149; i >= 0; i--) {
        assert(*(int *) stack_peek(stack) == i);
        assert(*(int *) stack_pop(stack) == i);
    }
    stack_destroy(stack);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

#endif                          /* TEST_MAIN */
```

### Review Request:

What I am mainly interested in are my new overflow checks and reallocation strategy, namely in `stack_create()`, `stack_push()`, and `stack_pop()`.

Other comments are also welcome.

**Edit:**

This is how it can be used:

```
#define GSTACK_IMPLEMENTATION     // Include the implementation as well
#define GSTACK_STATIC             // Make all functions static
#define TEST_MAIN                 // Include a sample main() function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Name space**

Code is taking up `stack`, `stack_...`, `Stack`, `STACK_...`.

I can foresee user code collisions as "stack" is very common.

Consider something like `gstack`, `gstack_...`, `GSTACK_...` and *not*  `gStack`.

**... an improvement to round this up ...**

```
        /* Would it be an improvement to round this up to the nearest
         * multiple/power of 2. */
```

No.  Rounding up makes sense only if you understand `STACK_MALLOC()` better than the implementer of `STACK_MALLOC()`.

**Really going to test this well?**

Do you really want linear growth of say a `BUFSIZ` of 4k when `SIZE_MAX` is 2<sup>64</sup> - 1?

Instead when geometric growth not possible either:

- Fail.
- Use `SIZE_MAX/memb_size` to simplify testing.  Fail if above that.

I'd go for the first.

**Why 4?**

[Magic numbers vs named constants](https://stackoverflow.com/q/608856/2410359).

`if (s->size && (s->size <= s->cap / 4)) {` deserves explanation.

**Unclear why `!!`**

As the return type is `bool`, why `!!`?  What benefit do you see?

```
// return !!++s->size;
return ++s->size;
```

**Why define `IO_STATIC`?**

```
 * To make all the functions have internal linkage, i.e. be private to the
 * source file, do this:
 * #define IO_STATIC
 * before including "stack.h"
```

**Where are `IO_...` defined?**

Code is for a generic stack type.  Does it compile with a generic C compiler?

```
#if defined(IO_MALLOC) != defined(IO_REALLOC) || defined(IO_REALLOC) != defined(IO_FREE)
    #error  "Must define all or none of IO_MALLOC, IO_REALLOC, and IO_FREE."
```

**1 .h file vs. a .c and .h file**

This `.h` file brings in  various `#include <....h>` files that would not be needed with classic .c, .h file approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
```

Unclear why code always includes `<stdio.h>`, `<stdint.h>`.

[Edit]
**Tolerate `stack_destroy(NULL)`**

As `free(NULL)` is OK, allow `stack_destroy()`.  This simplifies caller's clean-up code.

```
STACK_DEF void stack_destroy(Stack *s) {
  if (s) {  // Add condition
    STACK_FREE(s->data);
    STACK_FREE(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: *"Where are IO_... defined?"* ==> Like the opening comment states, one can define these to replace the standard `malloc()`, `realloc()`, and `free()`. That's the approach stb-libraries take, and `IO_STATIC` is an idiom I took from them too.

Comment: " That's the approach stb-libraries take," -->  `stb-libraries` and `IO_STATIC` are not in the standard C spec.  Are you coding to the C spec?  Please post link to _approach stb-libraries take_.

Comment: Oops, I thought I had added a link in the follow-up too. I have edited the question now.

Comment: @Harith How is `IO_STATIC` used here?  Comments suggest to define it, (without explanation) and then code does not use it.

Comment: It wasn't used in the sample main program, because it was in the same file. I have added an example now. It is only now that I realize that `IO_STATIC` has been a typo for `GSTACK_STATIC` all along.

Answer (score 1):

**Use-after-free bug:**

In `stack_pop()`:

```
    --s->size;
    void *const top = (char *) s->data + (s->size * s->memb_size);
        
    if (s->size && (s->size <= s->cap / 4)) {
        void *const tmp = realloc(s->data, s->cap / 2 * s->memb_size);
        
        if (tmp) {
            s->data = tmp;
            s->cap /= 2;
        } 
        /* Else do nothing. The original memory is left intact. */
    }
```

The lifetime of `s->data` ends with the call to `realloc()`, assuming it succeeded, so `top` is pointing to a block of memory that might have already been freed whilst shrinking.

GCC 12.3 caught the bug with `-O1 -Wall -Werror -Wpedantic`.

```
In file included from <source>:269:
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:291:16: error: pointer used after 'realloc' [-Werror=use-after-free]
  291 |         assert(*(size_t *) gstack_pop(stack) == i);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In function 'stack_pop',
    inlined from 'main' at <source>:291:9:
<source>:238:27: note: call to 'realloc' here
  238 |         void *const tmp = realloc(s->data, s->memb_size * new_cap);
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

If you remove `-O1` it doesn't detect anything. GCC 13.1 and 13.2 did not detect the bug, or if they did, they did not output anything.

Valgrind also reports a read error for this in `stack_pop()`.

The solution is to move the statement to the end of the function:

```
return (char *) s->data + (s->size * s->memb_size);
```

This also eliminated the variable `top`.

**Incomplete documentation:**

The documentation should include a warning about pushing function pointers onto the stack, as function pointers may not be compatible with a `void *`.

**Aside:**

`stack_is_empty()`, `stack_is_full()`, `stack_size()`, and `stack_peek()` are pure functions and may benefit from `__attribute__((pure))`. They are not constant functions because they're accessing global memory.

Comment: " pushing function pointers onto the stack, as that would invoke undefined behavior." --> How would _pushing_ invoke UB?  Perhaps popping and using the pointer when its original size > `void *`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Because a `void *` and a function pointer are not compatible according to  (6.3.2.3 Pointers) *"8 A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."* Or is my understanding of it awry?

Comment: Your quote 1) does not certainly imply incompatibility - only potential incompatibility.  2) The _push_ does not invoke UB - hence the problem with " pushing function pointers onto the stack, as that would invoke undefined behavior." .  The _pop_ does not invoke UB.  The potential UB is a function call with the pointer after the push, pop.  " If a converted pointer is **used** to call "  --- IOWs, the concern is good, but the place where UB occurs is mis-placed.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That makes sense. What would you suggest I change the documentation to?

Comment: Perhaps "The documentation should include a warning about pushing function pointers onto the stack, as function pointers may not be compatible with a `void `."