# Shunting yard calculator in C

Tags: algorithm, c, calculator

I'm new to C, and made this program that parses a string expression into a linked list post-fix expression, and then evaluates it, without parsing the string beforehand. Wondering if there is anything to improve/fix (I feel like my implementation is kinda big...)

main.c

```c
#include "util.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

Node *parse_to_postfix(char *expr);
long double evaluate_postfix(Node *expr, int *err);

int main(void) {
    char expr[200] = {0};

    while (1) {
        fgets(expr, 200, stdin);

        if (strncmp(expr, "quit", 4) == 0) {
            break;
        }

        Node *parsed = parse_to_postfix(expr);

        if (parsed != NULL) {
            int err;
            long double result = evaluate_postfix(parsed, &err);

            if (err == 0) {
                printf("= %Lf\n", result);
            }
        }
        memset(expr, 0, strlen(expr));
    }

    return 0;
}

Node *parse_to_postfix(char *expr) {
    Stack *output = stack_create(NULL);
    Stack *op_stack = stack_create(NULL);
    Node *bottom = NULL;
    int first_node_created = 0, previous_node_is_op = 1;
    char *num_buf = calloc(strlen(expr) + 1, sizeof(char));

    if (num_buf == NULL) {
        perror("error:");
        abort();
    }

    for (char c = *expr; c != 0; c = *++expr) {
        if (isspace(c)) {
            continue;
        }

        int c_is_op = is_operator(c);
        int converted_num = 0;

        // convert num_buf to long double and push to output
        if ((c_is_op || c == '(' || c == ')') && strlen(num_buf) > 0) {
            stack_push(output, node_create(strtold(num_buf, NULL), TYPE_NUMBER));
            memset(num_buf, 0, strlen(num_buf));
            converted_num = 1;
        }

        if (c_is_op) {
            // convert - into -1 *
            if (c == '-' &&
                ((op_stack->top != NULL &&
                  (previous_node_is_op || (op_stack->top->value_type == TYPE_PAREN && !converted_num))) ||
                 output->top == NULL)) {
                c = '*';
                stack_push(output, node_create(-1, TYPE_NUMBER));

                // simulate having -1 * take precedence over right associative operators
                if (node_check_valuetype(op_stack->top, TYPE_OPERATOR) &&
                    !is_left_assoc(op_stack->top->operator)) {

                    stack_push(op_stack, node_create(c, TYPE_OPERATOR)); // push * to op_stack
                    goto exit_ifs;
                }
            }

            while (node_check_valuetype(op_stack->top, TYPE_OPERATOR) &&
                   ((is_left_assoc(c) && get_precedence(c) <= get_precedence(op_stack->top->operator)) ||
                    (!is_left_assoc(c) && get_precedence(c) < get_precedence(op_stack->top->operator)))) {

                stack_push(output, stack_pop(op_stack)); // pop from stack to output
            }
            stack_push(op_stack, node_create(c, TYPE_OPERATOR)); // push c to op_stack
        } else if (c == '(') {
            stack_push(op_stack, node_create(c, TYPE_PAREN));
        } else if (c == ')') {
            while (!node_check_valuetype(op_stack->top, TYPE_PAREN) && op_stack->top->paren != '(') {
                stack_push(output, stack_pop(op_stack)); // pop from stack to output
            }
            free(stack_pop(op_stack)); // free left parenthesis
        } else {
            num_buf[strlen(num_buf)] = c;
        }

    exit_ifs:
        // set reference to first node added to output
        if (!first_node_created && output->top != NULL) {
            bottom = output->top;
            first_node_created = 1;
        }

        previous_node_is_op = c_is_op;
    }

    // convert any left over digits in num_buf
    if (strlen(num_buf) > 0) {
        stack_push(output, node_create(strtold(num_buf, NULL), TYPE_NUMBER));
    }

    // pop remaining operators in op_stack to output
    while (op_stack->top != NULL) {
        stack_push(output, stack_pop(op_stack));
    }

    if (!first_node_created && output->top != NULL) {
        bottom = output->top;
    }

    stack_free(op_stack);
    free(output);
    free(num_buf);

    // debugging purposes
    // Node *head = bottom;
   
    // while (head != NULL) {
    //     node_print(head, 0);
    //     head = head->previous;
    // }
    // printf("\n");

    return bottom;
}

long double evaluate_postfix(Node *expr, int *err) {
    Stack *stack = stack_create(NULL);
    Node *previous = expr->previous;

    *err = 0;

    while (expr != NULL) {
        previous = expr->previous;

        if (node_check_valuetype(expr, TYPE_NUMBER)) {
            stack_push(stack, node_remove(expr));
        } else if (node_check_valuetype(expr, TYPE_OPERATOR)) {
            if (stack->top == NULL || stack->top->next == NULL) {
                printf("error: syntax error\n");
                *err = 1;
                break;
            }

            Node *a = stack_pop(stack), *b = stack_pop(stack);
            long double result;

            switch (expr->operator) {
                case '+':
                    result = b->number + a->number;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    result = b->number - a->number;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    result = b->number / a->number;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    result = b->number * a->number;
                    break;
                case '^':
                    result = pow(b->number, a->number);
                    break;
            }
            free(a);
            free(b);
            free(node_remove(expr)); // free operator from expression
            stack_push(stack, node_create(result, TYPE_NUMBER));
        }
        expr = previous;
    }
    long double whole_result = (node_check_valuetype(stack->top, TYPE_NUMBER)) ? stack->top->number : 0;

    stack_free(stack);
    node_free(expr);

    return whole_result;
}
```

util.c

```c
#include "util.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void node_print(Node *target, int newline) {
    if (target == NULL) {
        printf("cannot print NULL node\n");
        return;
    }
    char nl = (newline) ? '\n' : ' ';
    switch (target->value_type) {
        case TYPE_NUMBER:
            printf("%Lf%c", target->number, nl);
            break;
        case TYPE_OPERATOR:
            printf("%c%c", target->operator, nl);
            break;
        case TYPE_PAREN:
            printf("%c%c", target->paren, nl);
            break;
        default:
            printf("node has no declared value type\n");
    }
}

Node *node_create(long double value, enum NodeType type) {
    Node *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));

    if (new == NULL) {
        perror("error:");
        abort();
    }

    new->next = NULL;
    new->previous = NULL;

    switch (type) {
        case TYPE_NUMBER:
            new->number = value;
            break;
        case TYPE_OPERATOR:
            new->operator=(char) value;
            break;
        case TYPE_PAREN:
            new->paren = (char)value;
            break;
        default:
            printf("error: no matching NodeType\n");
            return NULL;
    }
    new->value_type = type;

    return new;
}

Node *node_insert(Node *target, Node *previous, Node *next) {
    if (previous != NULL) {
        previous->next = target;
    }
    if (next != NULL) {
        next->previous = target;
    }
    target->previous = previous;
    target->next = next;

    return target;
}

Node *node_remove(Node *target) {
    if (target == NULL) {
        printf("error: cannot remove NULL node\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    Node *previous = target->previous, *next = target->next;

    if (previous != NULL) {
        previous->next = next;
    }
    if (next != NULL) {
        next->previous = previous;
    }
    target->next = NULL;
    target->previous = NULL;

    return target;
}

void node_free(Node *target) {
    if (target != NULL) {
        Node *prev_target = target->previous;

        while (target != NULL) {
            Node *next = target->next;
            free(target);
            target = next;
        }

        target = prev_target;
        while (target != NULL) {
            Node *previous = target->previous;
            free(target);
            target = previous;
        }
    }
}

Stack *stack_create(Node *head) {
    Stack *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));

    if (new == NULL) {
        perror("error:");
        abort();
    }
    new->top = head;

    return new;
}

void stack_free(Stack *target) {
    if (target != NULL) {
        node_free(target->top);
    }
    free(target);
}

Node *stack_push(Stack *target, Node *node) {
    if (target != NULL) {
        if (node == NULL) {
            printf("error: cannot push NULL node to stack\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        Node *prev_top = target->top;

        target->top = node;
        node_insert(node, NULL, prev_top);

        return node;
    } else {
        printf("error: cannot push on undeclared Stack\n");
        return NULL;
    }
}

Node *stack_pop(Stack *target) {
    if (target != NULL) {
        Node *top = target->top;

        if (top == NULL) {
            printf("error: cannot pop NULL node from stack\n");
            return NULL;
        }

        Node *new_top = top->next;
        Node *popped = node_remove(top);

        target->top = new_top;
        return popped;

    } else {
        printf("error: cannot pop on undeclared Stack\n");
        return NULL;
    }
}

int is_operator(char target) {
    switch (target) {
        case '+':
            break;
        case '-':
            break;
        case '/':
            break;
        case '*':
            break;
        case '^':
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int get_precedence(char operator) {
    switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            return 1;
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '/':
            return 2;
        case '*':
            return 2;
        case '^':
            return 3;
        default:
            printf("error: cannot get precendence of unknown operator '%c'\n", operator);
            return 0;
    }
}

int is_left_assoc(char operator) {
    switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            return 1;
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '/':
            return 1;
        case '*':
            return 1;
        case '^':
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("error: cannot get associativity of unknown operator '%c'\n", operator);
            return 0;
    }
}

int node_check_valuetype(Node *target, enum NodeType type) {
    return (target == NULL || target->value_type != type) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

util.h

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_UTIL_H
#define INCLUDE_UTIL_H

enum NodeType { TYPE_OPERATOR, TYPE_NUMBER, TYPE_PAREN};

typedef struct Node {
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *previous;
    union {
        char operator;
        char paren;
        long double number;
    };
    enum NodeType value_type;
} Node;

typedef struct Stack {
    Node *top;
} Stack;

// print value of node
void node_print(Node *target, int newline);

//  allocate node
Node *node_create(long double value, enum NodeType type);

// insert node between two nodes
Node *node_insert(Node *target, Node *previous, Node *next);

// update surrounding nodes and return popped node
Node *node_remove(Node *target);

// free all nodes that are connected to target
void node_free(Node *target);

// free all nodes and stack
void stack_free(Stack *target);

// allocate new stack
Stack *stack_create(Node *head);

// push node to stack
Node *stack_push(Stack *target, Node *node);

// pop node from stack
Node *stack_pop(Stack *target);

// if char is an operator * / + - ^
int is_operator(char target);

// get precendence value of operator
int get_precedence(char operator);

// return 1 if operator is left associative
int is_left_assoc(char operator);

// check if node matches type, return 0 when NULL
int node_check_valuetype(Node *target, enum NodeType type);

#endif
```

I compiled them using these gcc flags:

```
gcc 13.2.1:
-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c17 -g -lm
```

Comment: A stack, implemented as a vector/dynamic array whose top is at the end, would have much better performance than a linked list.

Comment: If I come back to do a full review, it will definitely mention the `while(1)` and `goto exit_ifs` as things to refactor.

Comment: When passing pointers, indicate if the pointer is constant, or the pointer is pointing to constant data or a constant pointer to constant data.  Inquiring minds will want to know if the function modifies their data.

Comment: If you want to evaluate an expression, there are alternatives to shunting yard. A recursive descent parser is (usually) easier and shorter. Take a look at Wikipedia article for an example. Shunting yard convert from infix to postfix but if expression is already in postfix it says like that (eg: "4 2 +" will be considered as a valid expression by your parser). This might not be what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on the idea of an array for the stack, the `Node` type wouldn't need to hold pointers and you wouldn't have to allocate a `Node` on the heap. This would eliminate much of the memory management, such as this bit:

```c
free(a);
free(b);
free(node_remove(expr));
```

---

I would rather have something like `Error evaluate_postfix(Node *expr, long double *result)` rather than returning the error via pointer. Although, I'd much prefer `parse_to_postfix` to check for syntax errors instead.

---

`evaluate_postfix` shouldn't consume `*expr`. You wouldn't expect a function with that kind of a name to have side-effects. `main()` owns `expr` so it should be responsible for freeing it.

---

`parse_to_postfix` is too complex. Much of the complexity comes from handling the unary minus. I think you could better handle it by treating it as a part of the following number. If the previous token is anything but a number or `)`, then `-` is unary and you could put it into `num_buf`.

I would also separate the parsing of numbers into its own function. Instead of pushing digits to `num_buf`, you'd call `parse_number(&expr)` when you encounter a digit (or a unary minus or some other number character), which would consume all following digits (and other bits of a number) from the input and return the number's value. In fact, `strtold` would do this for you.

---

What happens if parentheses don't match in the input? Particularly if there's no `(` before `)`, it seems your code would produce a very non-informative error message: `error: cannot push NULL node to stack`.

Comment: Thank you, you’re right, an array would definitely be less complex and easier than a linked list. On the other note, I prefer the current way of handling the unary minus because it treats it as separate , ex -2^2 = -4 not 4.

Answer (score 7):

```c
while (1) {
    fgets(expr, 200, stdin);
    ...
}
```

What happens if `fgets()` fail? You are ignoring its return value.

---

```c
if (strncmp(expr, "quit", 4) == 0) {
    break;
}
```

There's no way I'd have known to enter `quit` to exit had I not read the source code.

---

```c
memset(expr, 0, strlen(expr));
```

What's the point of setting `expr` to all zero bytes when it is just going to be overwritten and null-terminated by `fgets()`?

---

```
Node *parse_to_postfix(char *expr);
```

We wouldn't require this forward declaration if we define `parse_to_postfix()` before `main()`.

---

```c
char *num_buf = calloc(strlen(expr) + 1, sizeof(char));
```

`sizeof(char)` is defined by the standard to be 1. You can safely elide it.

---

```c
if (num_buf == NULL) {
    perror("error:");
    abort();
}
```

There's no need to cause *an abnormal termination* here. Simply do `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`.

---

```
if (isspace(c)) {
    continue;
}
```

`isspace()` expects an `unsigned char`, not a `char`.

---

```
Stack *output = stack_create(NULL);
Stack *op_stack = stack_create(NULL);
```

The return values go unchecked. Why return a null pointer on `malloc()` failure if you were simply going to ignore it?

---

You are computing the length of `num_buf` thrice in `parse_to_postfix()`. Consider using an extra variable to save the length.

---

```c
// debugging purposes
// Node *head = bottom;
   
// while (head != NULL) {
//     node_print(head, 0);
//     head = head->previous;
// }
// printf("\n");
```

This is no longer required.

---

```c
printf("error: syntax error\n");
```

Error messages go to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

---

```c
Node *a = stack_pop(stack), *b = stack_pop(stack);
long double result;

switch (expr->operator) {
    case '+':
        result = b->number + a->number;
        break;
```

The above would invoke undefined behavior if `stack_pop()` returns `NULL`.

---

```c
case '/':
    result = b->number / a->number;
```

This would invoke undefined behavior if `a->number` was 0.

---

```
Node *parse_to_postfix(char *expr);
```

`parse_to_postfix()` expects a non-null pointer, and it must be declared as such:

```
Node *parse_to_prefix(char expr[static 1]);
```

Same goes for the rest of the functions. This requires C99 albeit.

---

```c
void node_print(Node *target, int newline) {
    if (target == NULL) {
        printf("cannot print NULL node\n");
        return;
    }
    char nl = (newline) ? '\n' : ' ';
```

`newline` only needs to denote two states here, so it should be of type `bool`. (Include `stdbool.h` prior for the definition of `bool` prior to C2X.)

The parentheses around `newline` are also unneeded.

---

```c
Node *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
```

`new` is a bad identifier name since it is a reserved keyword in C++. Even if you never care for porting/compatibility with C++, you should still avoid naming identifiers after keywords from that language, since IDE style formatting tends to have a "C/C++" setting and then it will format `new` in weird ways.

Note that you can drop the parentheses around `*new`.

---

```c
if (target == NULL) {
    printf("error: cannot remove NULL node\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

Instead of printing an error message to `stdout` - which should really have been `stderr` - just return `NULL`. Nobody wants a library to print random stuff to `stdout`/`stderr` in their code, especially without their knowledge.

---

```c
int is_operator(char target) {
    switch (target) {
        case '+':
            break;
        case '-':
            break;
        case '/':
            break;
        case '*':
            break;
        case '^':
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This over-engineered function can be simplified to:

```c
return strchr("+-/*^", target) != NULL;
```

Or you could use `memchr()`.

Or:

```c
return target == '+' 
       || target == '-'
       || target == '*'
       || target == '/'
       || target == '^';
```

---

```c
int get_precedence(char operator) {
    switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            return 1;
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '/':
            return 2;
        case '*':
            return 2;
        case '^':
            return 3;
        default:
            printf("error: cannot get precendence of unknown operator '%c'\n", operator);
            return 0;
    }
}
```

You could use a map for this:

```
int get_precedence(char operator) {
    struct {
        const char op;
        const unsigned int precedence;
    } ops = {
        {'+', 1},
        {'-', 1},
        {'/', 2},
        {'*', 2},
        {...}
    };
```

But that might be overkill. Or you could merge cases:

```c
case '+':
case '-':
    return 1;
case '/':
case '*':
    return 2;
case '*':
    return 3;
default:
    return 0;
```

---

```c
int is_left_assoc(char operator) {
    switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            return 1;
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '/':
            return 1;
        case '*':
            return 1;
        case '^':
            return 0;
        default:
            printf("error: cannot get associativity of unknown operator '%c'\n", operator);
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Same goes for this:

```c
case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/':
    return 1;
default:
    return 0;
```

---

```c
int node_check_valuetype(Node *target, enum NodeType type) {
    return (target == NULL || target->value_type != type) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

This can be simplified to:

```c
    return target && target->value_type == type;
```

#### Some comments on the stack implementation:

I believe you have overly complicated it. Like @Davilsor suggests, a dynamic array with its top element at the end would have been more performant, more maintainable, and easier to implement. It would also have respected [principle of locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference).

I also do not like that `stack`'s internals are known to the client, i.e. its definition is included in `util.h`. I would have expected it to be an opaque type, with `get_top()`, `get_size()` et cetera.

The functions that are internal to the implementation should be defined as having internal linkage, i.e. marked `static` in the translation unit, and their declarations should be removed from the corresponding header file.

Consider using a common prefix for all the symbols. Currently, you have `stack_`, `node_`, et cetera.

Comment: Thank you too, how you shortened down those switch statements was something new to me

Comment: @expoodo You're welcome. See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/290857/generic-stack-implementation-revision for an array based stack implementation.

Answer (score 3):

**`double` math?**

`.number` is a `long double`.

I'd expect `result = pow(b->number, a->number);` to generate a compiler warning.  Save time and enable all compiler warnings and use `powl()` with `long double` arguments.

**Better output choice**

`printf("%Lf%c", target->number, nl);` can print many uninformative digits with larges values and simply zeros with small non-zero values.  Better to use `printf("%Lg%c", target->number, nl);` which switches to exponential notation for large/tiny values.

Even better, use `printf("%.*Lg%c", LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG, target->number, nl);` to print useful significant digits.

Comment: Thank you,  I never got any warnings for using long doubles on pow(). Do I just have to manually enable that warning or are there any else that cover it?

Comment: @expoodo See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154630/recommended-gcc-warning-options-for-c